# void error in Arrays.sort() in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String text1 = "check";

char c[] = Arrays.sort(text1.toCharArray());
```

Output:

```
error: incompatible types

    char c[] = Arrays.sort(text1.toCharArray());
    required: char[]
    found:    void
    1 error
```

Why does it not work that way?

Comment: `sort` is a destructive void method.

Answer (score 13):

The `Arrays.sort()` method has a return type of void, meaning it does not return an object/primitive, so you can't really assign the absent return value to a `char[]`.  The array will be sorted through the reference to it (arrays are objects) passed to the method.

BTW, the same applies for `Collections.sort()`

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5b%5d%29)

**FIX**

```
String text1 = "check";
char c[] = text.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(c);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.sort();` returns `void` you cannot assign it to an char array i.e `char[]`

Answer (score 3):

Note that   `Arrays.sort` does not return type.

Source code is as follows:

```
public static void sort(char[] a) {
    DualPivotQuicksort.sort(a);
}
```

If you want to sort the char array
You can use the following way:

```
    String text1 = "hello";
    char c[] = text1.toCharArray();

    //Sort char array
    Arrays.sort(c);

    //Print [e,h,l,l,o]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays.sort() returns void not char[]